# Get pending request count in gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn

I have deployed flask app using gunicorn and nginx in my dev environment. Now I need to check  pending request count in gunicorn. This is because I need to capture the metrics and post it to metrics server.
I have containerized the flask app. Please let me know how I can get the state of Queue in gunicorn ?

Comment: FYI. A relevant [github issue](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1808) suggests this is not possible natively, as `requests are queued at the by the operating system in the TCP listen backlog of the server socket`.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the same. I thought of knowing if anyone has already implemented any solution.